# Android: New tag collected - Unknown tag type

Tags: android, nfc

I've made an application that scans tags with the NFC scanner. Instead of the default Tag app, my app starts when a card is read.

It works completely, but there's one thing that is rather annoying: when I scan a card very fast, my application don't seem to respond, but the default Tag app opens (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGwiM.png). Is there any way to disable the default app or to start my app quicker?

Comment: What intents are showing up in the logcat? Can you paste the output here? What do you mean by scanning it very fast, do you move the phone away quickly before it has a chance to get all the data? This might be why.

Comment: This is what I receive:

02-10 11:30:32.023: I/ActivityManager(109): Starting: Intent { act=android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.google.android.tag/com.android.apps.tag.TagViewer (has extras) } from pid 194
02-10 11:30:32.312: I/ActivityManager(109): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.apps.tag/ndef_msgs/19 flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.google.android.tag/com.android.apps.tag.TagViewer (has extras) } from pid -1



Yes, I meant when I move the phone away quickly. I know that's the cause, but I want my app to be shown.

Answer (score 7):

Go to settings -> Apps -> All -> Tags(in my case) -> disable it

Comment: yes disabling the tags from the settings will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

I assume you filter for NDEF_DISCOVERED in your app currently and this is the case that works. If so, I would add a TECH_DISCOVERED intent for now, making sure you add a technology that your card supports so that your app can catch this corner case. From the logcat, I can't figure out what technology this tag is, so can't help you figure this out.

After your app can filter for TECH_DISCOVERED, read the data that is on the tag and see if it actually has the complete payload. If it doesn't then this would suggest the scan isn't picking up the entire payload and that moving your phone quickly away is a limitation of NFC itself. If the payload is the complete payload, then I would consider this a bug. Please report back.

Comment: The problem is most likely due to the phone not having enough time to check the card for NDEF data. As the card has disappeared prematurely, there is no real solution here. As NDEF_DISCOVERED is meant to be not dependent on a specific technology (NfcA, NfcB, IsoDep, NfcF, NfcV), I would not add a TECH_DISCOVERED intent filter for this case.

Comment: Any solution to this problem? I've got similar problem right now.